# Informal derivation of the Unruh temperature

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, vacuum, dimensional-analysis, qft-in-curved-spacetime, unruh-effect

Imagine a charged particle of mass $m$ at rest in the electromagnetic vacuum.

The particle interacts most strongly with zero-point modes that have a wavelength $\lambda_C$ similar to the Compton wavelength of the particle
$$\lambda_C \sim \frac{\hbar}{mc}.\tag{1}$$

When the particle is at rest it is in equilibrium with the zero-point modes around it.

Now imagine that the particle has an acceleration $a$. We consider an inertial frame instantaneously at rest with respect to the particle.

The uncertainty in the time coordinate of the particle, $\Delta t$, is related to the uncertainty in the particle energy $\Delta E\sim mc^2$ by the Uncertainty principle:
\begin{eqnarray}
\Delta t \Delta E &\sim& \hbar, \\
\Delta t &\sim& \frac{\hbar}{mc^2}.\tag{2}
\end{eqnarray}
The uncertainty in the velocity of the particle, $\Delta v$, is given by

$$\Delta v \sim a \Delta t.\tag{3}$$

Using Eqn.$(2)$ and Eqn.$(3)$ we find that the strongly-interacting zero-point modes in the direction of the acceleration have their energy [Doppler-shifted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_effect#General) by the amount $\Delta E_{+a}$ given by
\begin{eqnarray}
\Delta E_{+a} &\sim& m c^2 \frac{\Delta v}{c}, \\
\Delta E_{+a} &\sim& \frac{\hbar a}{c}.\tag{4}
\end{eqnarray}

In the opposite direction the strongly-interacting zero-point modes have their energy shifted by:

$$\Delta E_{-a} \sim -\frac{\hbar a}{c}.\tag{5}$$

The particle gains energy $\Delta E\sim\Delta E_{+a}-\Delta E_{-a}$ so that its temperature $T$ is given by:
\begin{eqnarray}
\Delta E &\sim& \frac{\hbar a}{c}, \\
k_B T &\sim& \frac{\hbar a}{c}, \\
T &\sim& \frac{\hbar a}{ck_B}\tag{6}.
\end{eqnarray}
Eqn.$(6)$ is roughly the [Unruh temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unruh_effect#Temperature_equation).

The particle emits its excess energy as a real photon in the direction opposite to its acceleration. This is consistent with an apparent horizon forming behind the particle at a distance $\lambda_U$ given by:
\begin{eqnarray}
\Delta E &\sim& \frac{\hbar a}{c},\tag{7} \\
\frac{\hbar c}{\lambda_U} & \sim & \frac{\hbar a}{c}, \\ 
\lambda_U &\sim& \frac{c^2}{a}.
\end{eqnarray}

Does this "derivation" of the Unruh temperature have any validity?

The particle's acceleration could be due to it sitting on the surface of a gravitating body so that this photon energy must originate from the vacuum itself rather than the particle or the gravitating body.

Comment: In natural units the formula you derived is $T\sim a$. This is the only thing allowed by dimensional analysis, so at this level you can get it by saying any words you like until you get something with temperature units.

Comment: How do you know that your system is thermal? I.e. what is the justification for equating $\Delta E$ with $k_BT$? In Unruh or Hawking radiation, this motivation stems from the fact that the expected vacuum no. density is Planckian. it is far from clear whether such identification will work in this case.